# Identifier Not defined in Macro

Tags: c++, macros

I was trying the below program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MKSTR(x) #x
#define CONCATE( x , y ) (x)##(y)

int main()
{
    int xy = 100;
    cout << MKSTR(HELLO C++) << endl;
    cout << CONCATE(HELLO,C++) << endl;
    cout << CONCATE(x,y) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and getting the error

> error C2065: 'HELLO' : undeclared identifier

. I don't see see why the VS 2012 compiler is expecting the macro argument or is treating them as identifier. Also the `MKSTR` macro worked fine but the `CONCATE` macro is giving me trouble. Can't understand why compiler is doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate symbols first, and then expand it in a string, like this (compiles in `GCC 4.8.1`) :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MKSTR(x) #x
#define CONCATE( x , y ) x ## y
#define CONCATESTR( x , y ) MKSTR(x ## y)

int main()
{
    int xy = 100;
    cout << MKSTR(HELLO C++) << endl;
    cout << CONCATESTR(HELLO,C++) << endl;
    cout << CONCATE(x,y) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
HELLO C++
HELLOC++
100
```

EDIT :

So for the question of why `MKSTR(CONCAT(...))` is not working, the reason is because of the expansion order of macros.
Because `CONCAT` is a parameter of `MKSTR` and `MKSTR` uses operator `#`, the argument is not expanded but instead immediately stringified. You could do this instead to make it work :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define CONCATE( x , y ) x ## y
#define MKSTR(x) #x
#define MKSTR2(x) MKSTR(x)
#define CONCATESTR( x , y ) MKSTR(x ## y)

int main()
{
    int xy = 100;
    cout << MKSTR2(HELLO C++) << endl;
    cout << MKSTR2(CONCATE(HELLO,C++)) << endl;
    cout << CONCATE(x,y) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and it will output what you expect.

Comment: Thanks I was assuming that the concatenated string would be printed also instead of defining a new macro  CONCATESTR I tried doing something Like MKSTR(CONCATE(HELLO,Cpp))  any idea why this wont work.

Comment: @Surfing_SO Edited just now for your new question